# Testing numerical integration in multiple dimensions

Tags: c#, testing, numerical-integration

I require test functions in multiple dimensions whose definite integrals are precisely known, so that I may test my numerical integration methods. I would like to test a wide variety of functions, with particular interest in ones that have some non-differentiable parts. I am trying to model insurance policies which have deductibles and maximums, which cause sharp corners in function space, but no spikes.

One particular result I seek is to understand how discretization error varies as the number of dimensions grows.

Code in C# is appreciated, but any function easily represented by the C# math library will be welcomed.